# Veutify animating v-data-table

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

> ```
> <v-data-table         
>     :headers="headers"
>     :items="rows"
>     :items-per-page="30"
>      class="elevation-1">
>
>           <template slot="rows" slot-scope="props">
>               <td>{{props.rows.username}}</td>
>               <td>{{props.rows.password}}</td>
>           </template>
>           <template v-slot:item.view="{ item }">
>               <button v-on:click="viewUser(item.userId)" class="btn btn-outline-info">View Patient Data</button>
>           </template>
>           <template slot="rows" slot-scope="props">
>           <td>{{props.rows.email}}</td>
>           </template>
>   </v-data-table>
> ```

How do I make it so every time a new row appears it fades in rather than "just appearing"?

Thank you

Comment: Can you please share the complete component code and rows object.?, if possible create a codepen, that will really help in resolve the issue

Comment: I'd like a row to fade out when deleting. Seems impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It is possible to add animation transitions to vuetify data table when adding new rows**

> Working codepen here: https://codepen.io/chansv/full/GRROZXd
>
> https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/GRROZXd

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
   <v-card>
    <v-btn @click="addRow" color="primary">click to add row</v-btn>
     </v-card>
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      class="elevation-1"
      hide-default-footer
    >
      <template v-slot:body="props">
        <tbody name="fade" is="transition-group">
          <template >
          <tr class="row" v-for="(item, index) in props.items" :key="index">
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.calories}}</td>
            <td>{{item.fat}}</td>
            <td>{{item.carbs}}</td>
            <td>{{item.protein}}</td>
            <td>{{item.iron}}</td>
           </tr>
            </template>
      </tbody>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>

Added this css

.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
        transition: all 1s;
      }
      .fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
        opacity: 0;
      }
.row {
  display: table-row;
}

In script

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%',
        }
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addRow() {
      this.desserts.push({
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%',
        });
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer. Your layout is different from mine. I have two buttons per row. Is it possible to do the fade in with my layout?

Comment: Yes I can make changes with you layout, for that I need rows and headers object.., also if possible , you can create a codepen and share a link